# How to display in my view multiple countdowns (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html, countdown

I am building a daily deal app to learn Ruby on Rails.

I display now for each deal the time until the deal is no longer available with Rails method (i use the gem dotiw that improves the classic distance_of_time_in_words)

I'd like to improve that and show a "live countdown" for each deal, like prizeo.com for example does here: http://www.prizeo.com/prizes

I need for each deal on the same page a different countdown as each finish at a different time.

Is there a pure html5 technique to do that? or maybe a Rails gem?

How would you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

User jQuery countdown clock and place as many of them on the page as you need, each one ticks on its own.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html